# W3wp againt asp.net development server

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, w3wp

can you explain w3wp ,,attaching to w3wp while debugging asp.net internal layers is good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erm, what? :-) w3wp is just the worker process for an application pool in IIS. Every app pool has one or more worker processes so a failure in a single application pool doesn't kill the whole server (assuming you've used different app pools for each app :-))

What else is there to know? :-)

Comment: my project has 4 layers DAL,,BO,,ServiceWrapper,,UI solutions
i need to debug from UI to Dal how to do for this..Now i am finding methods calling ,,for eg in UI 
client = new ContentAdministrationServiceClient();
                client.SetFaq(ref faq); here i will put break point in
SetFaq

Comment: in ContentAdministrationServiceClient of servisewrapper and attach that to w3wp,,is there any other way

Comment: If it's ASP.Net then you should connect to the aspnet_wp process.

Comment: aspnet_wp is only for IIS 5 IIRC.  W3WP is the right process to attach to in IIS 6 and newer.

Answer (score 1):

To attach a debugger set a break point in code that you know will be run (make sure that Debug="True" so that debug symbols are created) and in Visual Studio go Debug -> Attach to Process -> find your site's app pool's w3wp process. If you have several application pools active then w3wp will be listed more than once.

To step into your DAL you will need that compiled with debug symbols as well.

Answer (score 0):

W3wp.exe is the "World Wide Web Worker process". I don't see any reason or benefit to attach to it because it will not enable you to debug your ASP.NET application.

If you intend to debug ASP.NET applications, you should be attaching to the `aspnet_wp.exe` process (which is what Visual Studio does when you press Debug).